# JavaScript objects from Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 4

Tags: javascript

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TkV2y/3/

```
var chineseBox = {}; //create an object
chineseBox.content = "chineseBox"; //put a key/value pair inside chinesebox
alert(chineseBox); // why does the alert display { Object object }?
alert("content" in chineseBox); //returns true, as expected 
alert("content" in chineseBox.content); //why does this alert not show up??
```

My questions are:

1. Why, when I do `alert(chineseBox)`, do I not get the contents of the chineseBox object? I'd expected to see this:

   ```
   {content: "chineseBox"}
   ```

   Instead, I got `[object Object]` in the alert.
2. Why does the third alert I have there—`alert("content" in chineseBox.content);`—not show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That is the default `.toString()` implementation for objects in most JavaScript engines. To see the contents of the object, try: `alert(JSON.stringify(chineseBox));`
2. If you check the browser console, you'll find a type error. You cannot use the `in` operator on non-objects. This doesn't work (errors out): `'foo' in 'bar'`, but this does work (returns `false`): `'foo' in new String('bar')`

Answer (score -1):

1. Is the result of invoking `toString` upon an object Since they are objects and there is no specific format they should use, JavaScript wouldn't know how to serialize the object. If you want to see its content you need to use `JSON.stringify`.
2. The `in` operator searches for `content` inside an object. You can not search for `content` inside a primitive value since it has no methods or properties; hence, it will fail. You can test this by searching in a empty object; you'll see you get `false` as a response.

Comment: `.toString()` on an array would normally not return `[object Object]`.

Comment: no primitive value has methos, if something has amethod is an object

Comment: "bar" is not a primirive  as {} is not either, they might be literals but not primitives

Comment: @icktoofay what i said is that "bar" is not a primitive if you try to invoke anything in it it might be a literal like {} although you don't use new explicitly they both turn into objects i never said {} was a prmiitve